# Terminal command to clean tmp folder and set permission flags

Tags: permissions, graphics, tmp

Because of a low-graphics error I am not able to log into my system any more, or at least I am not seeing any graphical interface (solutions here [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) have been tried).

`df -h` revealed that my /dev/sda6 partition is full:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6 7.4G 6.6G 398M 95% /
udev 1.9G 4.0K 1.9G 1% /dev
tmpfs 762M 424K 762M 1% /run
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /run/shm
overflow 1.0M 4.0K 1020K 1% /tmp
/dev/sda7 449G 266G 161G 63% /home
/dev/sda1 447M 115M 308M 28% /boot
```

and

`sudo du -kxa / | sort -nr | head` leads to the output

```
sort: write failed: /tmp/sortXXXXXX (X = any number or letter): 
No space left on device
```

Therefore my question, how do I clean this `/tmp/sortXXXXXX` folder or directory with terminal commands and how do I set permission flags for that folder or directory to the standard value? I assume I messed up this permissions and now every process is writing to `tmp`.

Comment: Added `df -h` output.

Comment: That question does have answers about low disk space

Answer (score 1):

Your problems it isn't the /tmp, your problem is the full partition.

The sort command use a file to store temporal data, you haven't space to do it.

Try to make some space deleting old logs:

```
sudo find /var/log/ -name "*.gz" -exec rm -v {} \; 
sudo find /var/log/ -name "*.0" -exec rm -v {} \; 
sudo find /var/log/ -name "*.1" -exec rm -v {} \;
```

You can do more space cleaning the apt cached files:
    sudo apt-get clean
    sudo apt-get autoclean

Comment: Thanks! Did that. The first command deleted quite some files but still; `sudo du -kxa / | sort -nr | head` gives me `sort: write failed: /tmp/sortGA4Fww: No space left on device`. How may I see what exactly is taking up the space there?

Comment: Can you check if you have space with the command?: "df -h" Did you have /tmp mounted at other filesystem. Can you copy and paste the output of the comand "mount" and "df -h"

Comment: As `/tmp` is on its own partition deleting those files in `/var/` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have /tmp as virtual RAM disk, disable it by editing the file /etc/fstab and comment or remove the line that start with /tmp.
Reboot your computer.